# Wordpress loading an old file that does not exist

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I edited a JavaScript file that had +mon_url+ that I changed to +islmthm_url+. Like so,

```js
<label class="islmthm_radio_img"><input type="radio" name="newsbox-style" value="2"><img src="'+mon_url+'/framework/shortcodes/images/bg-9.png"><i></i></label>\
<label class="islmthm_radio_img"><input type="radio" name="newsbox-style" value="2"><img src="'+islmthm_url+'/framework/shortcodes/images/bg-9.png"><i></i></label>\
```

However, in the console, it shows me an error:

```
newsbox.js?wp-mce-4403-20160901:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: mon _url is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (newsbox.js?wp-mce-4403-20160901:36)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:2)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.ready (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:2)
    at a.fn.init (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:9)
    at n (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,farbtastic&ver=4.7.3:2)
    at newsbox.js?wp-mce-4403-20160901:23
    at newsbox.js?wp-mce-4403-20160901:367
```

Even though mon_url does not exist anymore.. what do I do? This error appears while I am trying to add a new post. I am developing this theme locally using WAMP.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: I did yes and I even used a different browser

Comment: Never Mind ... I cleared the cache again and it worked.. Thanks alot for your help